# Better way to pack numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to pack a numpy 2D array with struct.pack, and I'm seeking a method which can do this in a batch. I tried:

```
X = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = struct.pack('=%sf' % X.size, *X)
```

but this doesn't work. It prompts:

`struct.error: pack expected 6 items for packing (got 2)`

Is there a better way to pack the NumPy array instead of looping over each element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemed the '*' operator combined with struct.pack only works with 1D array. So for ND array, it has to be flattened to 1D firstly.

```
X = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = struct.pack('=%sf' % X.size, *X.flatten('F'))
```

This works for me.

Comment: The `*` is effectively iterating over the rows of the 2d `x`, giving you 2 `1d` arrays.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a numpy array, you already have your data packed in memory, you don't need to use `struct`:

```
>>> a = np.arange(1, 7)
>>> struct.pack('=6f', *a)
'\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00@@\x00\x00\x80@\x00\x00\xa0@\x00\x00\xc0@'

>>> a.astype('f').tostring()
'\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00@@\x00\x00\x80@\x00\x00\xa0@\x00\x00\xc0@'
```

And if your array is multidimensional, `.tostring` takes a flattened view by default:

```
>>> a = np.arange(1, 7).reshape(2, 3)
>>> a.astype('f').tostring()
'\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00@@\x00\x00\x80@\x00\x00\xa0@\x00\x00\xc0@'
```

Comment: I think 'astype()' does the similar job as 'struct.pack()' here. It's not already packed in memory, data conversion may be necessary

Comment: Indeed, but why use an additional module if you already have all you need in `numpy`?

Comment: That's true, it's always better to have an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

The `*` acts like an iterator.  Iterating on an 2d array returns the rows of that array.  For example:

```
In [9]: def foo(*args):
    print(args)    
In [10]: foo(*np.ones((2,3)))
(array([ 1.,  1.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.]))
```

`args`, inside the function, is 2 tuples, each a row of the array.  That is why your `pack` got 2 items, rather than 6 (`x.size`).  When you flatten the array, `*` produces all 6 items.

```
In [11]: foo(*np.ones((2,3)).flat)
(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
```

But what's the purpose of this `pack`?